# Boot OS X install from one Mac on another Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

It seems I can't boot a system installed on one MacBook in another MacBook.

My laptop needs a few days of servicing, so I thought it would be easiest to clone an image of my OS X install on USB drive, then boot from this USB drive on another laptop. Unfortunately all I get is a grey "no-no" circle.

What I actually did was:

1. Using Disk Utility I cloned MacBook's (let's call it "A") boot partition onto USB partition.
2. I can successfully boot MacBook A using this cloned partition.
3. If I plug USB drive into another MacBook ("B") and turn it on: the operating system on USB partition appears as available in bootloader screen (with orange icon) - but I cannot actually boot from it. Screen remains grey and a grey disabled sign is displayed.
4. The same happens if I simply use original A's drive in USB case (so this is not a cloning problem).
5. The same happens if I try to boot MacMini using USB drive.

Is it normal behavior, that OS X install is bound to the computer it was installed on?

Is there something I can do to override this behavior and force my MacBook B to boot with operating system installed on A?

A is MacBook Retina 15" and B is MacBook Retina 13".

OS X version is 10.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Install a fresh copy of OS X 10.8 onto your USB disk (just download the installer from the Mac App Store and select the external disk as target drive).
2. Boot from the newly installed OS X.
3. [Using Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872), transfer your data and configuration files from MacBook A's startup disk. You'll have to select the option "From a Mac, Time Machine backup, or startup disk".[image]
4. Boot from the external USB drive.

I know it's not a clone, but Migration Assistant does fairly well and preserves all your data.
I did this when I had to transfer my system (OS X 10.9 on a "classic" MBP 13" late 2012) on my new SSD drive. It worked very well. I did not lose any data.

If it doesn't work, your problem may be that [you're trying to boot a version of Mac OS X earlier than what came with MacBook B](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2186). Maybe installing Mavericks will do the trick.

See [this article on Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159) in order to know the original OS X version shipped with your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for a nice tip! Does the migration assistant include some low-level things like, i.e. Apache configuration, MySQL databases, tools installed in /usr/local etc?

Comment: The minimum version requirement may be a reason actually. Both MacBooks were 10.8, but mine is still 10.8.2 while the other may have been shipped with >= 10.8.3. May this minor version number be significant?

Comment: I don't know about the minor changes between 10.8.2 and 10.8.3. When I migrated, `/usr/local` data was preserved, as well as MySQL databases. I had to reconfigure Apache, though.

Comment: Um, actually the configuration was not lost. It was saved in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous`. :-)

Comment: Actually 10.8.2 was the reason! I booted A from USB drive, updated OS X to 10.8.5 and it is booting successfully also on B since then! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, I would not have used Disk Utility to clone a boot volume, I would use SuperDuper! or CarbonCopy Cloner.

Just the same, I have encountered similar situations in the past, including one quite recently. Often, if the cloned volume will not boot, it is a hardware issue – the newer system often cannot be booted by an earlier OS (sometimes even with the same version #). In those instances, you should still also be able to perform a fresh install of the new OS on the cloned drive without having to lose the data, but you will need a way to boot from an OS installer disk, such as a Flash drive.

Comment: Can you explain why you are recommending third party software over the manufacturer? What's wrong with Disk Utility?